# Issue in setting session when going from www.site.com to site.com

Tags: session, cakephp

When i log in to my website/application

www.xyz.com

and dont log out of my session,right after that if i go to 
xyz.com instead of www.xyz.com it shows not logged in.

This happens both ways when i log into xyz.com and dont log out of my sesion and then go to www.xyz.com it shows iam logged out.
This should not be happening.I have already checked session variables and other settings but still cant figure out why this is happening
Can any one please help and advise on the issue.

Comment: The answer is simple: Don't use both ways of accessing your URL. Redirect from one to the other using htaccess and 301. See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/07/13/redirect-root-domain-to-www-subdomain/

Comment: But my client wants it both ways www.xyz.com and xyz.com .He does not want any redirection

Answer (score 0):

Check your [cookie domain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html).  If it is set to `www.xyz.com`, change it to `xyz.com`.

Comment: we have not set cookies in our components.

Comment: I think you'll need cookies to maintain a session.  Look in your browser for your cookies.  find the one for your site.  Is it set for www.example.com, or example.com?